# DHR: Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:NROW(x)) : Number of periods does not match number of orders

Tags: fft, sarimax

I have tried to perform a dynamic harmonic regression to obtain an arima model with exogenous variables and for that I used the code presented in https://otexts.com/fpp2/dhr.html. However, when running the code an error message is displayed.
Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:NROW(x)) :
Number of periods does not match number of orders

To build the model I used three monthly series with 43 data, where two of them are the exogenous variables.
The dataframe I used looks like this:

```
{> modeloajuste
   T_matrix  V_matrix  M Month
1  14.17802 0.8604688  1     1
2  15.79006 0.7736985  2     2
3  17.62116 0.8357023  3     3
4  22.05094 0.8797615  4     4
5  21.08723 0.2305717  5     5
6  20.03432 0.3423527  6     6
7  19.36241 0.3935543  7     7
8  19.55144 0.4312422  8     8
9  18.34461 0.2839403  9     9
10 17.88718 0.9743811 10    10
11 18.24095 0.5178554 11    11
12 16.43083 0.7020082 12    12
13 13.28446 0.9563793  1    13
14 15.71997 0.7737180  2    14
15 19.11637 1.0874646  3    15
16 22.06385 0.9277122  4    16
17 24.44772 0.3887426  5    17
18 20.27052 0.3137290  6    18
19 19.56379 0.3456929  7    19
20 19.33246 0.3433963  8    20
21 18.55662 0.3047316  9    21
22 17.25356 0.7940866 10    22
23 15.45711 0.6400765 11    23
24 15.87066 0.7007103 12    24
25 14.76583 0.6811891  1    25
26 16.48400 0.8756550  2    26
27 19.05038 0.6741369  3    27
28 21.45588 0.7876674  4    28
29 23.84894 0.3214968  5    29
30 21.70421 0.2775853  6    30
31 19.18367 0.1340960  7    31
32 19.76713 0.3197615  8    32
33 18.28757 0.5319219  9    33
34 16.93758 0.9814153 10    34
35 15.12334 0.6050203 11    35
36 14.12159 0.5645782 12    36
37 13.01696 0.8034560  1    37
38 17.56584 0.5185198  2    38
39 20.77130 0.6376224  3    39
40 21.75943 0.6357125  4    40
41 22.54398 0.3640080  5    41
42 20.19191 0.5674044  6    42
43 20.04843 0.1816656  7    43
>}
```

Where T_matrix and V_matrix are the exogenous variables and with these I build the xreg for the regression.

```
xreg <- cbind(Mes = model.matrix(~as.factor(modeloajuste$M)), 
                 mes = modeloajuste$Month, modeloajuste$T_matrix,
                 modeloajuste$V_matrix)
```

And this is how the xreg array looks like with the colnames change

```
> xreg
   Ene feb mar abr may jun jul ago sep oct nov dic mes     temp       Vel
1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1 14.17802 0.8604688
2    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2 15.79006 0.7736985
3    1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3 17.62116 0.8357023
4    1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4 22.05094 0.8797615
5    1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5 21.08723 0.2305717
6    1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   6 20.03432 0.3423527
7    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   7 19.36241 0.3935543
8    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   8 19.55144 0.4312422
9    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   9 18.34461 0.2839403
10   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  10 17.88718 0.9743811
11   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0  11 18.24095 0.5178554
12   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  12 16.43083 0.7020082
13   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  13 13.28446 0.9563793
14   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  14 15.71997 0.7737180
15   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  15 19.11637 1.0874646
16   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16 22.06385 0.9277122
17   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  17 24.44772 0.3887426
18   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  18 20.27052 0.3137290
19   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  19 19.56379 0.3456929
20   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0  20 19.33246 0.3433963
21   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0  21 18.55662 0.3047316
22   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  22 17.25356 0.7940866
23   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0  23 15.45711 0.6400765
24   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  24 15.87066 0.7007103
25   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  25 14.76583 0.6811891
26   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  26 16.48400 0.8756550
27   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  27 19.05038 0.6741369
28   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  28 21.45588 0.7876674
29   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  29 23.84894 0.3214968
30   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  30 21.70421 0.2775853
31   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  31 19.18367 0.1340960
32   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0  32 19.76713 0.3197615
33   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0  33 18.28757 0.5319219
34   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  34 16.93758 0.9814153
35   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0  35 15.12334 0.6050203
36   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  36 14.12159 0.5645782
37   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  37 13.01696 0.8034560
38   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  38 17.56584 0.5185198
39   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  39 20.77130 0.6376224
40   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  40 21.75943 0.6357125
41   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  41 22.54398 0.3640080
42   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0  42 20.19191 0.5674044
43   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0  43 20.04843 0.1816656
>
```

However, when inserting the xreg array into the auto.arima of the code, the above error is displayed

```
plots <- list()
for (i in seq(6)) {
  fit_arimax <- auto.arima(consumo, xreg = fourier(xreg, K = c(i,i)), seasonal = F, lambda = NULL)
  plots[[i]] <- autoplot(main = "",forecast::forecast(fit_arimax, xreg=fourier(xreg, K=c(i,i)), h = 12)) + 
    xlab(paste("K =", i, "AICC =", round(fit[["aicc"]],2))) +
    ylab("Consumo, MWh") }
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plots[[1]],plots[[2]],plots[[3]],plots[[4]], plots[[5]], plots[[6]], nrow=3)

Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:NROW(x)) : 
  Number of periods does not match number of orders
```

So far, I have not been able to find how to fix this error, could someone help me?